# Janela personalizada de senha para a mesma página

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria colocar uma senha na página quando ser acessada(simples), em uma janela(tipo alert) com senha que aparece antes de carregar a página, eu queria esse "alert" personalizado igual um modal ou qualquer janelinha personalizada...

bem simples mesmo gente é pagina infantil...

código que estou usando:

```
<script language=javascript>
senha = '123456';
senhadig = prompt("Digite a senha","")
if (senha != senhadig){
top.location.href='erro.html';
}
</script>
```

Importante que não dê para ver o fundo antes de digitar a senha correta...

Igual acima porém queria deixar personalizada, pode ser com jquery,
ja procurei em sites sobre caixas dialog mas não consegui...

Eu nao estou preocupada com segurança, é para crianças pequenas(alunos), para elas não avançarem sem permissão. mas eu coloco em unescape e uso noscript =D

Comment: Se você já sabe que poderia ser um modal, por quê não tenta fazer usando um modal?

Comment: pq não consigo colocar um codigo de senha no modal, só uma janela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar essa `div` como overlay, funciona do mesmo jeito e você pode personalizar com css e adicionar novos elementos `HTML` ao seu gosto.

```js
document.getElementById("concluir").onclick = function senha() {
  var senha = '123456';
  var senhadig = document.getElementById("senha").value;

  if (senha == senhadig){
    document.getElementById("over").style.display="none"
  }else if (senha != senhadig){
    window.location.href='erro.html';
  }
}
```

```css
#over {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#232323;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:999999;
}
.inp {
  width:600px;
  margin:30px auto;
}
.con {
  width:560px;
  margin:30px auto;
}
#senha {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    background: #E9EAEC;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-size: 2em;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
#senha:hover, #senha:focus, #concluir:focus{
 outline: 0;
 transition: all .5s linear;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #777;
}
#concluir {
  width:100%;
  background:#E9EAEC;
  color:#7e9ebc;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.label {
  display:block;
  padding:15px 15px 15px 0;
  color: #7e9ebc;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="over">
<div class="inp">
<label class="label" for="password">Digite a senha</label>
<input type="password" id="senha"/><br>
<button id="concluir">CONCLUIR</button>
</div>
</div>
<p>Pagina</p>
```

> - Coloque o `script` logo acima de `</body>`
> - Caso queira que o redirecionamento substitua a localização atual assim não sendo possível voltar para a pagina apenas clicando em voltar use: `window.location.replace` no lugar do `window.location.href`
> - Coloquei `document.getElementById("concluir").onclick =` para que ao inspecionar o `botton` não entregue facilmente qual `script` está executando a função, porém se não funcionar apague e adicione `onclick="senha()"` no `button` **assim:**
>     `<button id="concluir" onclick="senha()">CONCLUIR</button>`

Comment: aqui ta funcionando certinho do jeito que queria mas quando fui tentar fica estatico como se a função nao funcionasse, não sei oque ta errado to colocando o script, css e o html normal, tentei ate em um arquivo html mas tbm nao foi

Comment: coloque o script logo acima de `</body>`

Comment: ta do mesmo jeito, só mostra essa janela parada vc clica e nd

Comment: atualizei a resposta

Comment: consegui obrigada por esta e pela resposta de ontem tbm

Comment: tio mark eu to com um probleminha, eu uso um frame que em certa pagina pega a pagina inteira e mesmo eu colocando essa senha fora do frame ele abre por cima da senha, entao eu tentei usar o display:none e display:block mas comigo nunca funciona kkkk como colocar no codigo isso pro id do iframe fazer com o q o iframe só abre após a senha correta?

Comment: adicionei `z-index` na resposta, mas você pode copiar e colar no css do seu código. Em `#over` cole `z-index:999999;`, o `z-index` determina a profundidade do elemento, eu coloquei `999999` para ter certeza que nada vai estar acima, mas você pode colocar como preferir